# What's the best way to build up a form from 2 models with Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, forms, mixins

For a little app I'm having two models defined:

```
class Pressure (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    sys = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=_(u"systolic"))
    dia = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=_(u"diastolic"))
    pulse = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=_(u"Pulse"))
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_(u"Messurement timestamp"))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.timestamp.strftime("%y-%m-%d: %H-%M")

class Weight(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    weight = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=_(u"Weight"))
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_(u"Messurement timestamp"))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.timestamp.strftime("%y-%m-%d: %H-%M")
```

No I want to build a merged form for both of this where user and timestamp will be the same for both models. The rest of the files should be kind of optional. That means, if not given e.g. weight, there shall be no insert into database etc.

I was reading about mixins and some formsets, but lagging a good idea what's the best approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a single form to handle this. You simply need a view which handles forms for both models. The basic idea is simple: create two form classes and present both to the user rendered in the same `<form>` element. On submit, check that both forms are valid and when they are then save them both and send the user to the next page. It would look something like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils.timezone import now

from .models import Pressure, Weight


class PressureForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Pressure
        exclude = ('user', 'timestamp', )


class WeightForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Weight
        exclude = ('user', 'timestamp', )


@login_required
def submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
        pressure_form = PressureForm(request.POST)
        weight_form = WeightForm(request.POST)
        if all(form.is_valid() for form in [pressure_form, weight_form]):
            record_time = now()
            pressure = pressure_form.save(commit=False)
            pressure.timestamp = record_time
            pressure.user = request.user
            pressure.save()
            weight = weight_form.save(commit=False)
            weight.timestamp = record_time
            weight.user = request.user
            weight.save()
            return redirect('<insert-name-of-success-url>')
    else:
        pressure_form = PressureForm()
        weight_form = WeightForm()
    context = {
        'pressure_form': pressure_form,
        'weight_form': weight_form,
    }
    return render(request, '<insert-template-name>', context)
```

You don't need formsets or generic views to handle this. It's a simple and straightforward view. If you found yourself repeating this pattern often then you may look to creating some view classes to handle this. None of the built-in generics will do this for you.

Comment: Receiving `'WeightForm' object is not callable` on POST. No idea by now

Comment: Saving the `weight_form` was missing the actual call to `save`. I've made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 ModelFrom's for your 2 models. And in one of your forms exclude 'user' and 'timestamp' fields. In template put fields from both forms in one `<form>` tag. In view you should save form with 'user' and 'timestamp' first and then put data from it to instance created with second form:

```
class PressureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pressure

class WeightForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Weight
        exclude = ('user', 'timestamp')

def someview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pressure_form = PressureForm(request.POST) # user and timestamp is here
        weight_form = WeightForm(request.POST)

        if pressure_form.is_valid():
            pressure = pressure_form.save()

            if weight_form.is_valid():
                weight = weight_form.save(commit=False)
                weight.user = pressure.user
                weight.timestamp = pressure.timestamp
                weight.save()
```

Comment: Do you see any chance to get the second part into a class-based-view?